# Plural to singular of french words in python

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I have a list of words and I'm trying to turn plural words in singular in python, then I remove the duplicates. This is how I do it :

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('fr_core_news_md')

words = ['animaux', 'poule', 'adresse', 'animal', 'janvier', 'poules']
clean_words = []

for word in words:
    doc = nlp(word)
    
for token in doc:
    clean_words.append(token.lemma_)
    
clean_words = list(set(clean_words))
```

This is the output :

```
['animal', 'janvier', 'poule', 'adresse']
```

It works well, but my problem is that 'fr_core_news_md' takes a little too long to load so I was wondering if there was another way to do this ?

Answer (score 2):

The task you trying to do is called [lemmatization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemmatisation) and it does more than just converting plural to singular, it removes its flexions. It returns the canonical version of a word, the infinitive form of a verb for example.

If you want to use spacy you can make it load quicker by using the [`disable`](https://spacy.io/usage/processing-pipelines#disabling) parameter.
For example `spacy.load('fr_core_news_md', disable=['parser', 'textcat', 'ner', 'tagger'])`.

Alternatively, you use [treetagger](https://cis.uni-muenchen.de/%7Eschmid/tools/TreeTagger/) which is kinda hard to install but works great.
Or the [FrenchLefffLemmatizer](https://github.com/ClaudeCoulombe/FrenchLefffLemmatizer).